# Specialize C++ template for different but still same types

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization, specialization

I would like to specialize a template for two types which of both are based on the same basic type:

```
using myint=uint16_t; //16 bit integer
using myfxpt=uint16_t //8+8 bit fix point number
```

It is not possible to specialize a template for both, because both are `uint16_t`. However, according to the representation they are still different.

How could I find a workaround for this issue? Using a somehow transparent fixpoint class could also be a solution, but effectiveness is important. I don't know how I could write it so that after the compiler's optimization we got the same result.

Comment: Can you use `struct FixPtStruct { uint16_t fp; };`?

Comment: The `myint` and `myfxpt` are currently the same types. They are merely differently named aliases of the same type. You need the types to differ. For `myfxpt` you can use instead a struct with a suitable API - one that has the same operations for addition as `unit16` but different ones for multiplication to suit its pixed-point nature.

Comment: For maintainability I would like to use the type as if it was a basic type. I could define several features such as assignment `fxpt = myconst` and other operators, but I still do not know how efficient would be the final code. And even, I only need addition and subtraction, so the compiler's built in solution would be enough. Just handling these data should be different. (e.g. showing the value)

Comment: boost has a strong typedef

Comment: _but I still do not know how efficient would be the final code_ The same as a primitive type of the same size, with optimisation enabled.

Answer (score 1):

What you want are strong typedefs. C++ does not have them. Various proposals to add them have been made, but they raise questions to which there are no clear resolutions. For now, one way to fake it is to use enum classes:

```cxx
enum class myfxpt : uint16_t {};

constexpr myfxpt operator+(myfxpt lhs, myfxpt rhs) noexcept {
    return myfxpt{static_cast<uint16_t>(lhs) + static_cast<uint16_t>(rhs)};
}
constexpr myfxpt operator-(myfxpt lhs, myfxpt rhs) noexcept {
    return myfxpt{static_cast<uint16_t>(lhs) - static_cast<uint16_t>(rhs)};
}
// Same for all the operators you care about. Same for myint. Maybe use macros?
```

Written this way, for all optimization levels above `-O0` any compiler will optimize the operations as if they were directly on the underlying type.